# maven install error : 2.6 or one of it's dependicies could not be resolved

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat

I'm trying to deploy my maven project on the application server with apache tomcat. This is my first maven project and I don't think I will use maven again. After getting too many errors and solving it, the output of the latest error is as follows. I get this error when I run the mvn install command.

> Plugin.org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of
> its dependencies could not be resolved:Failed to read artifact
> descriptor for
> org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6:Could not
> transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:pom
> 2.6 from/to central https://repo1.maven.org/maven2:transfer failed to
> https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/2.6/maven-resources-plugin-2.6.pom:
> PKIX path building failed
> :sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuildException: unable to
> find valid certification path to requested target.

my pom file is as follows :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>level3</groupId>
    <artifactId>reports</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>reports</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <lombok-version>1.18.20</lombok-version>
     <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
     <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
</dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
  <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
  <artifactId>ojdbc10</artifactId>
  <version>19.3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
            <version>2.5.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
            <version>1.18.20</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <version>2.5.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
           <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
           <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.2</version>
</dependency>
    </dependencies>
    
    <build>
        <plugins>
        <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.4.RELEASE</version>
    </plugin>
         <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.6</version>
        </plugin>  

     <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </plugin>
    <plugin>   
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>   
    <version>3.2.3</version> 
    </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

also there is no company proxy setting. I've seen this in some solutions and it didn't work.

how can i fix this error?

Comment: Which version of Java are you using to run Maven?

Comment: ı'm using java 11

Comment: First mixing several versions of spring boot (not using spring boot parent? might be eaiser) furthermore having plugins as dependencies (simply wrong)..Also which Maven version do you use ? Have you correctly set JAVA_HOME ? Running from plain console or from within your IDE? Are you behind a proxy / firewall (corporate environment?) .. ?

Comment: I'm working from console , I set java_home correctly , not existing any proxy or firewall , apache maven version 3.8.4 and not using sprin boot parent . I'm about to go crazy if I don't solve this mistake